# Why do I get a "Platform Not Supported Exception" while adding new Response Header?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Why do I get a "Platform Not Supported Exception" while adding a new Response Header? I am debugging a website using Visual Studio web server.

```
Response.Headers["X-XRDS-Location"] = url
```

Exception Message:

> This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Response.Headers.Add() works only in IIS7 integrated pipeline mode.  Use Response.AddHeader() instead.  This method will work on all platforms.