# Visual Studio 2008 built-in web server needs integrated pipeline mode for Adding Http Header

Tags: visual-studio-2008, exception, http-headers, embeddedwebserver

Using Visual Studio 2008 and built-in web server.

In a Web Handler .ashx file

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

        context.Response.ContentType = MimeType_text_xvcard;
        context.Response.Headers.Add(HttpHeader_ContentLength, "2138");
```

when I try to add an HTTP header I get the exception:

> This operation requires IIS integrated
>   pipeline mode.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.PlatformNotSupportedException:
>   This operation requires IIS integrated
>   pipeline mode.

I can find information about this error on the Internet  but need specific info about how to presumably enable Integrated Pipeline mode (through web.config?) to allow HTTP headers to be manipulated.

How do do I put the built-in web server into integrated pipeline mode?
**Note:** Not using full-fledged IIS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833030/why-do-i-am-getting-platform-not-supported-exception-while-adding-new-response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing

```
context.Response.Headers.Add
```

with

```
context.Response.AddHeader
```

(courtesy of [this site](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_23136384.html))

I believe you have to be running IIS7 (in Integrated Pipeline mode) to use `Headers.Add`

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on your Web Project and Select "Use IIS Express..."

Comment: That's certainly an option, to switch web servers to another that uses integrated pipeline mode. I could even go so far as to set  up the website on full-fledged IIS - that would work too.